# How do I add permanent text before user enters a text in html textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I want to add a permanent text in html textarea before user enters a text like in cmd where path is written before you write any code.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check out [jQuery Terminal Emulator](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal). It's probably way overkill because it can be used as a functional command line interpreter, but I thought it was interesting. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qe6zx79k/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with JavaScript:

```js
$('textarea.text').each(function() {
  var prefix = $('<span/>')
    .text($(this).data('prefix'))
    .addClass('prefix')
    .appendTo('body')
    .css({
      left: $(this).position().left + 'px',
      top: $(this).position().top + 'px',
    });
  $(this).css({
    textIndent: prefix.outerWidth() + 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
textarea,
span.prefix {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 2px;
  border-width: 1px;
}

span.prefix {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="text" data-prefix="Your path or text > "></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, as far as I know, there's no built-in functionality for what you want.

But, combining a few things, we can achieve something close to it.

The trick is:

- Wrap the textarea within a `div` tag
- Use `::before` pseudo-element on the given `div` to add and position the fixed text
- Use `text-indent` css property on textarea to make room for our fixed text :)

```css
#cont {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#cont::before {
  content: 'myFixedText:\>';
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

textarea {
  text-indent: 100px;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get text in the textarea you can do this:

```
<textarea>Insert permanent text here</textarea>
```

Placeholder text will allow the user to type over it which is not permanent.

Comment: This text can be erased by the user, which is not exactly permanent either.

Answer (score 0):

Use the placeholder attribute as such:

```
<textarea placeholder="Describe yourself here..."></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to have a text before any typing in an input or textarea :

```
<input type="text" name="TheName" **placeholder=**"Type your name">
<textarea name="TheTextArea" **placeholder=**"Your textarea..."></textarea>
```

Comment: Placeholder gets removed a soon as user starts typing.

Answer (score -1):

Placeholder Attribute is the most common option for input and textarea. But value can also be used to an actual text there.
`<textarea value="Something here" placeholder="Something here">Something here</textarea>`

Comment: Note that: "If you want default content for your `<textarea>`, you enter it between the opening and closing tags. **`<textarea>` does not support the `value` attribute**," ([<textarea>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)).